# how to use jump to if I need to evaluate a condition of context variable for two different nodes at same time

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I have one parent node ,based on the user input Iam setting a context variable at my application level eligibility:yes or no and passing back.And for my parent node I have two child nodes for conditions $eligibility=="yes" and $eligibility=="no".So once users input from parent node validation is done and context variable is passed back ,then I need to jump and look for condition of eligibility.If yes I need to go one node ,if no then to other.How can I do?

[image]

I tried putting true to node and added these two nodes to this and jump to true..But didnt worked..How can we achieve this?

Comment: Have you set `eligibility` as context variable in the parent node? That nested processing is possible. I have an example here https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables#nested-evaluation-of-variables

Comment: @data_henrik I havent set..But why do we need to set there?

Comment: Where is it set? I assume you want to check it in the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

what @data_henrik has mentioned is a good way to set context value and then switch to different flows depending upon the set value. But when you need to perform some logic before setting that value in the context from your application, it won't be a suitable way.

I had a requirement like this, so we used to send a dummy text from our application after we were done with setting the value in context after the parent node execution. Check out the images and explanation after that.

[image: Dialog]

[image: Child Node]

We didn't use Jump because we had to do some validation in the Conversation service after parent node before moving forward. Using jumps would've allowed the Conversation to move to next node before we could set value in context.

**Use case flow -** once user enters text for the parent node intent, for my case "#send-mail" intent, I show the parent response and do some functional validation in my app after that and add a value to the context. Now we send a dummy text "valid" which satisfies the intent "#Valid" and hence move to the next node in flow. In this node we check for the value in context (which is already set by now) and show appropriate response to user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...But I need to have some set of dialog nodes for either of case..From your eaxmple,if we have $testMe==true I need some set of nodes to flow and similarly if $testMe==false .I need to have some set of dialog nodes not just displaying output..How can I do ??Appreciate any inputs on this

Answer (score 0):

You can set within your first two test nodes, $testMe==true and $testMe==false a temp output variable within the output json packet, i.e. output{"temp":"true"} or "false". Then you can jump to a new set of nodes and test for the output.temp value, i.e. output.temp == 'true' then do something, or output.temp == 'false' then do something. 
The nice side effect of this action is that the output.temp variable only has a life of that current conversation input. Unlike context variables which need to be removed / deleted.